# How to execute a job once at specific time in a specific timezone using Quartz scheduler

Tags: timezone, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to set a single execution of a job at a specific time in a timezone of a user using Quartz. Client machine and server machine are having different time zones.

SimpleSchedule does not allow me to set a timezone.

Another option is to convert all the times provided by the user to the timezone of a scheduler, and then create the trigger with that time. But, this doesn't perform well as performance point of view.

Please suggest me best approach

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to recalculate fire times, then it is best to use a Quartz trigger type that allows you to specify a time zone. For example, you can use a [CronTrigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html) with a [cron expression](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) as shown in the example below.

[image: Cron trigger with a time zone]